# Expression or word that means "a tactic is stolen by the enemy and used against oneself"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for something different from [Word for “to use someone's own tactics against them”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117160/word-for-to-use-someones-own-tactics-against-them). I'm considering a scenario in which one intends to use a certain tactic to defend oneself against some enemy. However, **before** the tactic can be used, it is stolen by the enemy and used against the person him/herself.

Example: Alex told the plagiarizer he'd sue them unless they delete the video. However, that only prompted the plagiarizer to ______ with a defamation lawsuit.

Comment: The answer could perhaps be "pre-emptive strike" but you haven't given any context. Could you give a description of a realistic scenario. What sort of tactic are you talking about? Is this in a war? Is it an argument with a neighbour or a spouse?

Comment: Whoso diggeth a pit shall fall therein (People who set traps for others get caught themselves.) -Proverbs 26:27

Comment: Isn't the "enemy" just using someone's own tactic against them? I'm not sure what real difference the distinction is besides point of view... I think [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/117168/148459) works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

**Beat to the punch**

> to do something before someone else does it.
>
> *I wanted to have the new car, but Sally beat me to the punch. I planned to write a book about using the new software program, but someone else beat me to the draw.*

- McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.

In this case, you can say that the enemy was planning to using a tactic, but you beat them to the punch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, "beat to the punch" suggests the two parties are equals and both aware of the tactic from the get-go. I've edited my question to illustrate the scenario I had in mind, to which this doesn't quite apply.